# JupyterQ license Check Failed

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kdb

Upon loading a JupyterQ notebook for a kdb project, I got an unfamiliar error.

**License check failed.**

There's an issue with the license manager. Check your installation carefully and/or reinstall your application.

I googled it and there's no explanation, other than to reinstall everything, which I did.

```
conda install -c kx kdb
conda install -c kx embedpy
conda install -c kx jupyterq
```

No change, still get the error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

64-bit kdb requires a license to run although it is free for non-commercial use with some limitations. Have you followed the steps outlined here to get the kc.lic file downloaded?

https://code.kx.com/q/ml/setup/#download-via-anaconda

Comment: I have, I've been using jupyterq for the last few months, this is a new error. I was using it a week ago but today this error pops up. I google it and I click here: https://github.com/KxSystems/jupyterq/blob/master/jupyterq_licensemgr/jupyterq_licensemgr/__init__.py
It seems to be a new error.

Comment: hmm yeah quite possibly a new error. May be worth emailing `ondemand@kx.com`

Answer (score 0):

Licences/binaries *'expires'* occasionally. Request new one, or download new binary.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same thing happen to me.
You need to replace this file in your anaconda3 folder
C:...\anaconda3\q\kc.lic
You can do so by downloading the licence from kx:
https://ondemand.kx.com/

This it is the free, non-commercial, 64-bit kdb+ on demand licence.
Fill in the info and they'll email you the license.